# VBA Delete all cells in each row except the last used cell

Tags: vba

Trying to write a script to delete all cells in a row except the last used cell, then move all remaining data to the first column.

See below:

```
|--| is an empty cell
|XX| is a cell with unneeded data
|DATA| is the cell with Data I require.

Before:
|--|--|--|XX|XX|XX|XX|DATA|
|--|--|XX|XX|XX|DATA|

After
|DATA|
|DATA|
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you meant in Excel:**

**Process:**

- Loop over the sheet
- Set a tempVal variable to the value of the lastColumn
- Loop through the columns to the last column for that row, clearing each cell
- Set the value of column A to the tempVal

**TESTED:**

```
Sub GetLastColumnValue()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim sheet As String
Dim tempVal As String

sheet = "Sheet1"
lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   'Using Range()

    For lRow = 2 To lastRow

        lastCol = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        tempVal = Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, lastCol).Text

        For lCol = 1 To lastCol
            Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, lCol).ClearContents
        Next lCol

        Sheets(sheet).Cells(lRow, 1) = tempVal

    Next lRow

End Sub
```